# Tools for decoding SQL injection attempts, locating vulnerabilities

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I would like to decode their hex requests, what tools would I need?

Also- are there good automated pen-test tools to explore possible vulnerabilities in my code?  I assume these exist as the requests I received were too rapid to be manual.

Sample request:

```
action=999999.9)+%2f**%2fuNiOn%2f**%2faLl+%2f**%2fsElEcT+0x393133353134353632312e39,0x393133353134353632322e39,0x393133353134353632332e39,0x393133353134353632342e39,0x393133353134353632352e39,0x393133353134353632362e39,0x39313335313
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools include:

- [WebScarab](https://web.archive.org/web/20180501160617/https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Webscarab)
- [Paros Proxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20171026190343/http://www.parosproxy.org:80/index.shtml)
- [sqlmap](https://sqlmap.org/)
- [BSQL Hacker](https://labs.portcullis.co.uk/tools/bsql-hacker/)

Articles:

- [Top 15 free SQL Injection Scanners](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230111753/http://rochakchauhan.com:80/blog/2008/01/10/top-15-free-sql-injection-scanners/)
- [Comparing SQL Injection Detection Tools Using Attack Injection: An Experimental Study](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5635053)
  (requires IEEE login)
- [Web application security: Testing for vulnerabilities](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/web-development/) (IBM.com)